# Generate signature in the backend

Tags: signature, node.js

I am building an app where I need to generate a message signed on the backend with NodeJS, something like `window.solana.signMessage('hello')`.
I have the user's private key, I just need a signature to authenticate the user, but I cannot find how to generate it on the server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NaCl tweet library to generate the signature on the server

```
     // Encode anything as bytes
      const message = new TextEncoder().encode("Your message here");
     // Sign the bytes using the wallet
     const signature = await signMessage(message);

     // Verify that the bytes were signed using the private key that matches the known public key
    
    const result = nacl.sign.detached.verify(
      message,
      signature,
      publicKey.toBytes(),
    );
     console.log("result",result);
    if(!result) throw new Error('Invalid signature!');
```

result will be true or false depending upon whether the user is signing the message using his own private key..
Hope this helps.

Comment: Works! [tweetnacl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tweetnacl) uses ed25519 just like Phantom and the signature is compatible. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71612774/what-is-the-algorithm-phantom-wallet-solana-uses-to-sign-messages) too.